# React/nodejs Cpanel project - frontend won't connect to backend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cpanel

okay so I am working on deploying a React/node js project on Cpanel, the frontend is being shown but any attempts to request to backend will result in either connection time out or on connection refusal. However, in the Cpanel virtual terminal the data from database is retrieved without a problem.

Since the virtual terminal uses localhost to call the database, I tried using localhost for the frontend but it resulted on connection refusal, if I tried using the shared IP address or the domain name, but it would then be timed out.

all I need is for the frontend to connect successfully to the backend.